# PHP site with SmartCard + local app for authentication

Tags: java, php, mysql, spring, smartcard

You can achieve SmartCard/PIN based authentication to a Java website using a portlet/servlet on the server side and an applet on the client side.

How would one go about achieving the same thing when you want the site to be a PHP website? (Although not a flat PHP/MySQL situation, but a 3-tier PHP→Spring WS→MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be creating a client in PHP that talks to Spring WS.

In Spring WS you can implement an API that can be used by PHP.

I'm not sure what smartcard you have and what protocol is used.

Comment: The card is a Mifare type card. I have a working portlet on JBOSS EPP and an applet for the client side. But seeking to migrate to a different platform, keeping the smart card authentication and signing features.